# Ubuntu 22.04 stops making sound

Tags: sound

In the last week, ubuntu periodically began to mute itself, stopped producing sound after an hour.

If I cold boot the computer, it produces sound.

If I warm reboot or restart after it mutes itself, it makes sound again.

**NO**, it is not the speakers.  Two computers share the same monitor and HDMI output to the speakers.  It does **NOT** happen with the other computer while ubuntu mutes itself.

**NO**, it is not the driver since it makes sound on bootup.

**NO**, the "mute" button is **NOT** on.

**NO**, the speakers are working and volume is up.  If I change the monitor to view the other computer running simultaneously, the other computer makes sound.

The "help" system is useless.  It's written by someone that assumes the user is always as fault, no solution offered when it's the OS at fault.

Ubuntu 22.04

Intel NUC11THNi3